# Rotation in configuration space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, rotation

Let $R_\psi$ be the rotation in configuration space around a vector $\bf{e}_\psi$ for an angle $\psi$.

How is that the space rotation in configuration space have:
$$(R_{\delta\psi_1}-1)(R_{\delta\psi_2}-1)-(R_{\delta\psi_2}-1)(R_{\delta\psi_1}-1)=(R_{\delta\psi_1\times\delta\psi_2}-1)$$
given that
$$\bf{r}\to\bf{r}'=R_{\delta\psi}\bf{r}=\bf{r}+\delta\psi\times\bf{r}=(1+\delta\psi\times)\bf{r}$$
Its easy to see that
$$(R_{\delta\psi_1}-1)(R_{\delta\psi_2}-1)-(R_{\delta\psi_2}-1)(R_{\delta\psi_1}-1)=\delta\psi1\times\delta\psi2\times-\delta\psi2\times\delta\psi1\times$$
But I don't see how that leads to
$$\delta\psi_1\times\delta\psi_2$$
Maybe is a simple question, but I can't seem to find the relation between the commutator and the cross product.
$$[\delta\psi1,\delta\psi2]-?\to\delta\psi_1\times\delta\psi_2$$
And is this kind of relationship apply to general(rotation) situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [rotation group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group) of three dimensional space has three [*generators*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Lie_algebra) $T^a$ given by

$$ T^1 = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right) \quad T^2 = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right) \quad T^3= \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$$

which yield rotations associated to a vector $\vec \phi \in \mathbb{R}^3$ by (summation over repeated indices implied in the following)

$$ R_{\vec \phi} = \mathrm{e}^{\phi^aT^a} = 1 + \phi^aT^a + \mathcal{O}(\phi^2)$$

and, by inspection, we see that they fulfill

$$ [T^a,T^b] = \epsilon^{abc}T^c$$

with $\epsilon$ the [Levi-Civita symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol). Now, recall that the cross product is given as

$$ (\vec v \times \vec w)^i = \epsilon^{ijk}v^i w^j$$

and that therefore, to first order (which is sufficient on the level of the Lie algebra)

$$ [\phi_1^a T^a,\phi_1^b T^b] = \phi_1^a \phi_2^b[T^a,T^b] = \phi_1^a \phi_2^b \epsilon^{abc} T^c = (\phi_1 \times \phi_2)^c T^c$$

Noting that $R_\phi - 1 = \phi^a T^a + \mathcal{O}(\phi^2)$ recovers your results for infinitesimal $\phi$.